verifying email from yahoo domain is not working in php
function smtp_validate_yahoo_email($email)
{
list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);

    // Specifically check for Yahoo domains
    $mxhosts = ['mta5.am0.yahoodns.net', 'mta6.am0.yahoodns.net', 'mta7.am0.yahoodns.net'];
    
    // Set timeout for socket connection
    $timeout = 10;
    $port = 25;
    $max_retries = 5;
    $initial_delay = 5;

    foreach ($mxhosts as $host) {
        $retry_count = 0;
        $delay = $initial_delay;

        while ($retry_count < $max_retries) {
            $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
            
            if ($connection) {
                fgets($connection, 1024);
                fputs($connection, "HELO example.com\r\n");
                fgets($connection, 1024);
                fputs($connection, "MAIL FROM: <info@example.com>\r\n");
                fgets($connection, 1024);
                fputs($connection, "RCPT TO: <$email>\r\n");
                $response = fgets($connection, 1024);
                
                if (strpos($response, '451') !== false || strpos($response, '421') !== false) {
                    fclose($connection);
                    $retry_count++;
                    sleep($delay);
                    $delay *= 2;  // Exponential backoff
                } else {
                    fputs($connection, "QUIT\r\n");
                    fclose($connection);
                    
                    return (strpos($response, '250') !== false) ? "Email is valid." : "Email is invalid.";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return "Yahoo mail servers could not be reached.";
}

It is always return invalid, i also tried so many libraries like Egulias\EmailValidator,EmailVerifier\EmailVerifier.
If I tried with my smtp server then it will always return valid.
so can you please help me to solve the yahoo mail validaton in php

Why not do what everyone else does and send the user a verification email, with a unique code in it which they must respond to, to confirm the email address is legitimate? Many mailservers will not let you do what you're trying to do here, anyway. Also you didn't actually tell us what was in $response when it comes back from the yahoo smtp server, so it's impossible for us to say what the specific issue might be.

thanks @ADyson, the $response is false

Ok. I don't know Yahoo's setup specifically (but I expect you can research it online), however I think it's unlikely they run a completely open SMTP server - most major providers don't these days. They likely expect some authentication and so on. So that could be a reason this isn't working. But it's really the wrong approach anyway...like I said, you will know from personal experience the way almost every site/app in the world verifies email addresses. Is there a specific reason you're not taking that reliable, well-tested route?

Ok thanks, actually i have a small team as well and i want to develop a small website like zerobounce but only for yahoo domain. so can you please guide me some approach that i can use for validation?

If you don't even know where to start with the core task you're supposed to do, how are you going to build a business out of that? Asking randoms online isn't really the way to go. But no I don't personally know how zerobounce implemented their service. I'd imagine it has a lot more to it than just throwing a few commands at an SMTP server though - since they've managed to monetise it I assume it's adding a decent amount of value, rather than being something anyone can build for themselves quickly.

Yes you are right. I will look for it. Thanks
